# Adding any data(entry) to the LDAP server using JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I want to add any data(entry) to the LDAP server. I tried the following code. One method to connect which works, and the other to add entry which doesn't work.

Any advice or solutions? 
I am attaching the screenshot of my LDAP server:

[image]

```
public static  DirContext connectJndi() throws NamingException {
    //method to connect to LDAP server using JNDI 
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>(); 
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.0.60:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "******");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "*******");
    //DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env); 
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
    return ctx;     // connection method works. 
} 

//this method doesn't work. 
public static void insertJndi( ) throws NamingException  {
    LdapContext ctx = (LdapContext) connectJndi();    //connecting to the server

    LDAPAttributeSet attrs = new LDAPAttributeSet();
    String objectclass_values[] = { "top", "person", "op","11" };
    LDAPAttribute attr = new LDAPAttribute("objectclass",objectclass_values);
    //Attribute objectClass = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
    attrs.add(attr);
    LDAPEntry myEntry = new LDAPEntry("cn=jin,c=kr", attrs);
     ctx.add(myEntry);
```

Comment: `//this method doesn't work. ` is not a a valid error decription

Comment: @Scary Wombat  ah  sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried other API instead and it worked. I was going to erase this question, but this might help some people, so I am copying my code here.  If not, I'll erase it.

```
public static void insertJndi( ) throws NamingException  {

    DirContext ctx = connectJndi();
    Attributes attributes = new BasicAttributes(); 
    Attribute objectClass = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
    objectClass.add("anything");
    attributes.put(objectClass);
    Attribute a = new BasicAttribute("a");
    Attribute b = new BasicAttribute("b");
    a.add("jin");
    b.add("lee");
    attributes.put(a);
    attributes.put(b);
    ctx.createSubcontext("cn=a002,ou=b,ou=c,ou=d,o=government of Mars,c=Earth", attributes);
    System.out.println("it worked");
```